# How to change the URL without page reload in Magento

Tags: ajax

I am developing a site like http://charitybuzz.com using Magento. If you can check they have shown all the products in home page and by clicking on a category the page URL changes but without any reload. I need the same thing done on my site, Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

[See the answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/2047249)

The idea is to make ajax calls for certain urls and then use `window.onpopstate`.
Something like this (copy/paste from the answer mentioned above).

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = e.state.html;
        document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
    }
};
```

You ajax response handling function can look like this (copy/paste again because of the lack of imagination)

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);
 }
```

you can make changed in `onpopstate` function in order to achieve the desired sliding or fading effects.

oh yeah...and not all the browsers support this. Only Chrome, Safari, FF4+, and IE10pp4+